# DocusignAPI SOAP via Post, NOT using any SDKs

Tags: authentication, soap, docusignapi

We are developing for one of your customers a method from our application (written exclusively in LiveCode Script) and need to utilise SOAP via a POST command directly from LiveCode. I eventually, after a lot of digging into the resources pages, found some reference on how to Post 'CreateAndSendEnvelope' from here:

[CreateAndSendSchema](https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx?op=CreateAndSendEnvelope)

However, it does not show where to place login credentials for the user or company or whatever so that it is attributed to the correct account.

I found [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404029/docusign-soap-api-guid-should-contain-32-digits-with-4-dashes-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xx) which kind of points me in the right direction, but do you not have any specific documentation on how to set up your headers and body when using XML for both authenticating and sending a document via email using SOAP?

Providing a simple guide demonstrating the header required and the basic XML to POST to send a document with tags for signing to a single recipient by email using a senders user credentials would be perfect.

Thanks

Sean.

Pi Digital Productions Ltd

Comment: Found this for the credentials schema: https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/credential.asmx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOAP is still using what we call "Legacy Auth" which is the older, less secure, (not OAUTH) authentication.
To use that, you still need an IK (Integration Key) but you provide the username, password and IK in clear text inside a header called X-DocuSign-Authentication that looks like this:

```
'X-DocuSign-Authentication: { "Username":"DocuSign@example.com",  "Password":"DocuSign_password",  "IntegratorKey":"DocuSign_Integrator_Key" }'
```